# How to count how many points intersect each polygon using SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Hi so I have database of Polygons and Points with geometry data. I want to see how many intersect per polygon just showing the count of polygons with points in them.

This my script of finding the intersected points and polygons:

```
SELECT NEATCELL FROM 
[dbo].[POLYGON] as p,[PLACES6].[dbo].[Points] as h
WHERE P.NEATCELL.STIntersects(h.PointsGEOM) = 1
```

Now I want to find how many points are there in each intersected polygon using the count function.So for this script I wanna do a count of how many points are there in neatcell. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query should get you the result you want:

```
SELECT 
    NEATCELL, 
    COUNT(*) AS NumberOfIntersections 
FROM 
    [dbo].[POLYGON] as p,
    [PLACES6].[dbo].[Points] as h
WHERE 
    P.NEATCELL.STIntersects(h.PointsGEOM) = 1
GROUP BY 
    NEATCELL
```

Comment: getting this error The type "geometry" is not comparable. It cannot be used in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I am having similar error.  Did the above syntax work for you or what did you change to get past the error?